# ZURB Foundation: "clearing" images won't change

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have just copied the example code but I can't get it working.

Example: http://goo.gl/wrw2v

The thumbnails have different sizes and the large images won't change, when I click on an thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the same html structure. Second image is not wrapped in a `<a></a>`.